# android php org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm very new to php, i'm trying to insert data into a mysql database using php but i'm getting the following error:

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
     $con = mysqli_connect("DBHOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD!", "DBNAME");

     $username = $_POST["username"];
     $password = $_POST["password"];
     $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

     $response = array();
     $response["success"] = true;  

     print_r(json_encode($response));
?>
```

and here is my logcat:

```
 04-30 15:55:06.585 11289-11289/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
 04-30 15:55:06.708 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System: ClassLoader     referenced unknown path:   /data/app/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi-1/lib/x86
 04-30 15:55:06.956 11289-11319/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
 04-30 15:55:07.062 11289-11319/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 04-30 15:55:07.094 11289-11319/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 04-30 15:55:07.094 11289-11319/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7e0740, error=EGL_SUCCESS
 04-30 15:55:19.158 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi.Login$2$1.onResponse(Login.java:85)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi.Login$2$1.onResponse(Login.java:80)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 04-30 15:55:19.159 11289-11289/com.google.android.gms.fit.samples.basichistoryapi W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The error i think is happening in this part of my code where the jsonobject is being pulled from the response :

```
Response.Listener<String> response = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success){
                                Log.i("Adding to DB:" , "SUCCESSS");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateProfile.class);
                                intent.putExtra("usernamesignup", usernamesignup.getText().toString());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Sign Up Failed :( ")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: Check the server's error log, or write the entire response to your logcat. There you will see the complete error message.

Comment: I posted the full error both in the body of the question and in the title. "Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject". My problem isn't not knowing what the error is, it's not knowing how to fix it or what's causing it.

Comment: And although you probably don't allow your server to be accessed from outside localhost, it is best to keep your db credentials secret.

Comment: The error you show is the exception raised by your app not the server. The `<br` is a part of the server's error message. To see all the error message, write the `response` to the logcat or check the server's log.

Comment: The response is too long to paste here but basically it says that the website requires javascript and that I need to enable javascript, but i don't have a webview at all, i don't understand why i'm getting this error

Comment: That's weird, what hosting are you using? Do they force advertisement? Can you upload the error somewhere and provide the link?